# UPNP Server for IP Web Cam

Tags: software-recommendation, webcam, upnp

I have a IP webcam and I want to serve the stream by a upnp server. What I need to do is simply; define a upnp device with the source url of IP web cam. Can you suggest such tool or script to do so ?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit difficult to answer without knowing how the web cam provides its stream.

One server that will probably be able to do what you want is `rygel`.  If you install it and the `rygel-gst-launch` plugin, you can configure it to serve arbitrary streams.

In the `~/.config/rygel.conf` file, you'd need to include something like:

```
[GstLaunch]
enabled=true
launch-items=webcam
webcam-title=Web Camera
webcam-mime=video/mpeg
webcam-launch=souphttpsrc location=http://url-to-webcam-stream
```

Depending on the details of your webcam, you might need a different `-mime` and `-launch` lines.  The launch line is a GStreamer pipeline description, as you might pass to `gst-launch-0.10` (minus the parts used to display/play the stream).

Comment: I'll try this once I got to office and let you know here with the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that with VLC, play around with the inputs and outputs, activate streaming and that should set you up. If you need help setting this up let me know and I'll write a small guide when I get home.

Comment: need to got to office to test the solution. thanks.